# ImportError: No module named testing

Tags: python, django, python-2.7, numpy, matplotlib

I am doing code in python for DBSCAN. After running the code, this error is shown:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "C:/Python27/n", line 1, in <module>
from matplotlib.pyplot import *
   File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\__init__.py", line 156, in <module>
from matplotlib.cbook import is_string_like
   File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\cbook.py", line 28, in <module>
import numpy as np
   File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\numpy\__init__.py", line 168, in <module>
from . import add_newdocs
   File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\numpy\add_newdocs.py", line 13, in <module>
from numpy.lib import add_newdoc
   File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\numpy\lib\__init__.py", line 8, in <module>
from .type_check import *
   File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\numpy\lib\type_check.py", line 11, in <module>
import numpy.core.numeric as _nx
   File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\__init__.py", line 46, in <module>
from numpy.testing import Tester
   ImportError: No module named testing
```

I have installed python 2.7, matplotlib 1.3.1, numpy 1.8.0, pytz, pyparsing, six

How to resolve this issue?

Comment: Can you please show your code? There is an error with module import.

Comment: It is most likely that your packages aren't installed correctly (wrong version, development snapshot ...)